# select a part of the image by putting 4 points on the image to define using JQuery

Tags: jquery, image

I want to select a part of an image not with the common method [like this](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos/tutorial1.html)  but putting 4 points to define the image. These 4 points represent the vertices of the rectangle.
Do you have some idea of how can I proceed ?

Comment: 2 points are enough to define a rectangle. 4 point will define a quadrilateral.

Comment: I've found the answer on this question on stackoverflow  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128073/how-to-select-a-polygonal-area-of-an-image-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 0;
$(".yourclass").click(function(event) {x++;
if(x==1){
    X1 = event.clientX;
    Y1 = event.clientY;
}
else{
    X2 = event.clientX;
    Y2 = event.clientY;
}
});
```

in this way you can get the x,y axis of both points.

Make a div and make its background image this with background positions as these values.. Hope that would help.